# how draw in realtime to tableLayout - in android with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

i build a table 3*3 for the game x vs 0, and i need to draw into the cells x or 0,
i dont know how to do it in realtime ' please help!
this is a part from the table
i a new developer at android so i need your help

```
    </TableRow>
            <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="#FF260A" />

    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

How will you trigger the draw? Will it be by the user clicking on the table cell? If so, you can create a onclick Listener for each TextView view element, and use this to set the text for the clicked view.

If you create a custom view that extends TextView, with the relevant onClick listener in, you can use this for the cell contents in the layout.

I've done something very similar for my Android games, extending ImageView with a custom view to handle moving cells around, but I'm at the day job so I don't have access to any sample code to show you at the moment. However, this tutorial on creating custom views might point you in the right direction:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html